# pandas to_json changes index type of dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am reading a CSV file and transforming it to dataframe and then to json in order to send it via api.

The problem is after reading the json and re-transforming it into dataframe, index type changes to `Int64Index` in place of `Index`

Here is what I do to send my DF:

```
df=pd.read_csv('/tmp/'+file, sep=urllib.parse.unquote(sep), encoding=encoding, dtype=dt, decimal=decimal)
# Here, df.Index gives Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], dtype='object', name='Code')
return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': df.to_json()
        }
```

and then I receive it with:

```
x=pd.read_json((json.dumps(json.loads(r.text)))) # r is the body from first part
# And here x.Index gets transformed to Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64', name='Code')
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: x.Index is not returning the same result. I want to keep this format Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], dtype='object', name='Code')

Comment: Is it sufficient to recast the Index back to strings after you import it?

Comment: Any code examples to how can it be done please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To map the index back to strings you can use

```py
df.index = df.index.map( str )
```